# Mocking a repository in Spring boot and testing a rest API

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, repository

I am trying to mock the two repositories present in the below MsgController :

InflowRepository and OrderRepository

and test the rest endpoint: path = "/api/msg/inflow" from another TestController.

I am getting error when I write the below statement in the TestController:-

Comment: it would be better if you post the error here

Comment: The method thenReturn(Optional<Order>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Optional<Order>> is not applicable for the arguments (Order)

Comment: Unresolved compilation problem!

Comment: And you expect us to guess how your full test class looks? Please add the class instead of 4 lines. Return `Optional.of(order)` instead of the order directly.

Comment: @M.Deinum  - Hello, Thank you so much for your help. It worked after adding Optional.of(order) . Could youo please explain me this term please?

Comment: That is what your return type of the method you are mocking is. It was an optional not an order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try : doReturn

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);

when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");
doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-